# Design View Model as internal class

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on Windows Runtime Component project which must expose few Controls to the outside world. I would like to use Design View Models so I have something like:

```
public sealed class FirstPanelDesignViewModel
{ ... }
```

It works as supposed during design time but this class is also exposed to the outside world of its project, a thing which is not desirable. So I can modify it like this:

```
internal class FirstPanelDesignViewModel
{ ... }
```

But now the Designer (.xaml file which is opened) complains that it cannot access the class and the render does not occur anymore:

`The name "FirstPanelDesignViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "using:SomeProject.DesignViewModels".`

Is there a way to use Design View Models in a Windows Runtime Component without exposing it to the outside?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use [Friend Assemlies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx)

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System;

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("AssemblyB")]

// The class is internal by default.
class FriendClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sample Class");
    }
}

// Public class that has an internal method.
public class ClassWithFriendMethod
{
    internal void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sample Method");
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, so which Assembly should I add with InternalsVisibleTo("") so that the Designer will see the class?

Comment: You should add assembly which uses your class

Comment: But I'm working within the assembly which **contains** the class.

Comment: Ouch! I thought it was defferent assemlies :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704149/making-binding-property-internal-instead-of-public-in-viewmodel