# Displaying ListviewItem Properties In Grid Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, binding

So I've added a bunch of items to a `ListView`. All of the items added are structures that have 4 members. The members are `Amount`, `Location`, `Date_Time`, and `Category`. These members are setup as properties and I was trying to bind each member to a column in the `ListView`.

Unfortunately, my results are blank entries or the added structures ".tostring()" return value. Essentially I have no Idea how to correctly setup up the binding. Any ideas in XAML or C# would be appreciated. Also the structure resides in a separate class, not the MainWindow class that contains all the controls. Formatting and styling is still in the works for my listview so don't judge my bad color scheme.

Thanks

[image: Structure]

[image: Listview]

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use images to show us your code. StackOverflow allows to insert code snippets. Also use paragraphs to format your question. Always see on your question after you've posted it.
2. **Binding works only with public properties**. Change access modifier of your structure and its properties from internal to public. See answer at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704149/making-binding-property-internal-instead-of-public-in-viewmodel) topic.

Comment: Using an internal instead of a public access Modifier was the issue.