# DataGridView Showing Empty Rows when assigned to a List of Type containing internal properties

Tags: c#, winforms

I experienced an issue which kind of opposed my basic C# concepts on Access Modifiers. So i build a Sample application reproducing Same Scenario.

There is a Parent Form with Click Button on the event of which a new Form spawns with a DataGridView. The Data Source is static string,string and the properties are internal as i am using everything in the same project.

To my surprise, there were 5 rows made since i had 5 data items bind to that grid but were just empty Rows. Then i made the properties as public and i was able to get them. All the Rows were populated with correct Data the second Time.

**Parent Form**

```
namespace SampleApp{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<ItemModel> modelList = new List<ItemModel>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
        using (SeperateWindow window = new SeperateWindow(modelList))
        {
            window.PopulateGrid();
            if(window.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        for(int i= 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            ItemModel item = new ItemModel($"Name { i}", i.ToString());
            modelList.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**Model Class**

```
namespace SampleApp.Model{
sealed class ItemModel
{
    internal string Textvalue { get; set; }
    internal string ID { get; set; }
    internal ItemModel(string text,string id)
    {
        Textvalue = text;
        ID = id;
    }
}
```

**Child Form Containing GridView**

```
namespace SampleApp.Model{
public partial class SeperateWindow : Form
{
    List<ItemModel> _modelList = new List<ItemModel>();
    internal SeperateWindow(List<ItemModel> modelList)
    {
        _modelList = modelList;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void PopulateGrid()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _modelList;
    }
}
```

My issue is since everything is in the same project, and model class and child form are in the same Folder too, then also why am i getting Empty Rows? Given that it is working fine if i make them public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx)

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding **must be public properties** of your class. Explicitly defined interface properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected, private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base implementation.

Also please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704149/making-binding-property-internal-instead-of-public-in-viewmodel), in which the difference between `public` and `internal` keywords in databinding has been discussed.

Comment: That's quite an insight. This is all due to binding engine and PresentationFramework.dll which binds and thus cannot access the properties.
But shouldn't it give runtime exception in such case?

Comment: @priyankbhardwaj check the output window. If there is any it should be there.

Comment: well i've already checked this and nothing came in O/P window.